# Zip contents of a folder with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to zip the contents of a folder having dynamic name and save the resulting zipped file inside the same folder. The way I have done it does not work (gulp keeps thinking without throwing error or anything). My code is:

```js
gulp.task('zipfolder', function() {
  return gulp.src('staticfolder/dynamicNameFolder*/**/*')
    .pipe(zip('result.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('staticfolder/dynamicNameFolder*/'));
});
```

**Edit:** The name of the dynamic folder is 'dynamicNameFolder' + some number. As the number is unknown, I put **dynamicNameFolder***

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after dozens of tries, I found how to do it. I basically had to use 2 more gulp plugins: `fs` to read the dir path synchronously as well as `glob` to read the regexp pattern synchronously.

```js
var zip = require('zip');
var glob = require('glob');
var fs = require('fs');

var getDynamicFolderName = fs.readdirSync(staticPath + glob.sync('dynamicFolderName*'));
// inside the glob.sync you can use a lot of patterns and options (check documentation)

gulp.task('zipper', function() {
  return gulp.src(getDynamicFolderName + '/**/*')
    .pipe(zip('results.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(getDynamicFolderName));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your glob is wrong. `staticfolder/dynamicNameFolder*/**/*` won't work. You probably want something like: `staticfolder/dynamicNameFolder/**/*`. If you want this to be more dynamic you should probably do it like this:

```
gulp.task('zipfolder', function() {
  return gulp.src('staticfolder/' + dynamicDirName + '/**/*')
    .pipe(zip('result.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('staticfolder/' + dynamicDirName + '/'));
});
```

Of course you need to provide the variable `dynamicDirName` for it to work.

Comment: The dyanmicfolder's name keeps changing so I put * to say any folder containing the name dyanmicfolder and whatever that comes behind

Comment: So change folder name with variable.

Comment: Yeah, but the folder name is never the same. Keeps changing with build version number.

Comment: Its a task that runs when build is finished so I never know the folder name but just know the starting letters (here for example **dynamicNameFolder**)